# Script to calculate sum of odd or even file size - Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I need to write a shell script that will count total size of files which size is an
odd or an even number (depending on the parameter given in the command line at the time the
script is executed).

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -- "."
totsize=0
if [ "$2" == "odd" ]
then
        for file in "$1"/*
        do
                if [ -f "$file" ]
                then
                        size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
                        if ((size % 2 == 1))
                        then
                                ((totsize += $size))
                        fi
                fi
        done
else
        for file in "$1"/*
        do
                if [ -f "$file" ]
                then
                        size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
                        if ((size % 2 == 0))
                        then
                                ((totsize += $size))
                        fi
                fi
        done
fi
echo $totsize
```

The script should be executed ex. by typing **bash script2.sh ./tmp odd**

Unfortunately, the script goes directly to the "else" section.
What I have noticed is, that the second argument **odd** or **even** is not even passed to the script.

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think `set -- "."` does? Why do you use it?

Comment: The second argument is passed to the script, but the script resets it to the empty string.

Comment: to offer some action-oriented advice, does commenting out `set -- "."` solve your problem? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have used part of a code found on the Internet and modified it. That is why there is the entry 'set -- "."'. I have already tried to delete it, but then I always receive the value 0 as a final result, which is wondering me.